# Using integer field as variable date value for rolling period in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server 2012
I have a DateID field in integer format represented as YYYYMM
I need to set that field as a variable where every time the script is used, it finds the latest date/max DateID value and returns all records for the previous 12 months. Because of the format I see that would be the DateID-100 (because 201704 - 100 returns 201604, ie April 2016)

my total script looks like:

```
SELECT 
sum (isnull(Total_Items,0))
FROM [TABLE]
where Field1 = 'A'
and Field2 = 'B'
and Field3 = 'C'
and Field4 = 'D'
and dateid > 201604
```

It's that >201604 bit that needs to be the variable!

Grateful for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT( VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE()), 112) AS INT);
```

where

112 [specifies](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp) `yyyymmdd` (ISO) encoding

Comment: date format. updated SQL to give you last year date. this will result as 201606

Comment: you can see different date formats at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to just do:

```
select sum(Total_Items)
from [TABLE]
where Field1 = 'A' and
      Field2 = 'B' and
      Field3 = 'C' and
      Field4 = 'D' and
      dateid > year(getdate()) * 100 + month(getdate());
```

The logic seems easier to understand.

Also, you don't need to worry about `NULL` values with `SUM()`.  Aggregation functions generally ignore them anyway.  If you want to be sure that the `SUM()` never returns `NULL`, then you want `COALESCE(SUM(. . .))`.